# difference between executing script using bash file.sh and ./file.sh

Tags: bash, unix

Sometimes I have difficulty in running ./file.sh but I can run the command bash file.sh. What is the difference in the two commands? Does ./file.sh execute some other implementation of sh?

Comment: What is the `#!` interpreter being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "file.sh" is not executable then `./file.sh` will not work but `bash file.sh` will.

If "file.sh" does not start with the line `#!/bin/bash` (or another path to a valid bash interpreter) then `./file.sh` will not work but `bash file.sh` will.

Basically, in order for a script to look like an executable file it must:

1. Have execute permission.
2. Start with the line `#!/path/to/interpreter`.

Comment: It's also possible that the script has `#!/bin/sh` but actually requires Bash in order to work correctly; then the shebang should be changed to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash is being used

Comment: Note that `./file.sh` is generally preferred, since a script *should* be executable and have a proper shebang line; `bash file.sh` is best thought of as an override that should only be needed if there's something wrong with the script (in which case the better solution is: fix the script and use `./file.sh`).